# I'm using UISearchController, and while using it, search bar moves up/down when I click "cancel" button. Why does it happen?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have TableViewController: UITableViewController. 
I have implemented 
`let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)`. 
I use SearchBar as tableView.tableHeaderView
While I'm using search, SearchBar moves up/down when I click cancel button. Why does it happen?

```
   searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
   definesPresentationContext = true
   searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
   tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
   searchController.searchBar.returnKeyType = .done
   searchController.searchBar.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false
```

[check it](https://media.giphy.com/media/U1xHL7bTft9wVCbJGf/giphy.gif)

Comment: add this code to prevent animation `self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false`

Comment: @Vinodh I want to hide navigation bar when tap on searchBar

Comment: If you don't want the search bar to move from its position, specify `searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false` like Vinodh said. It moves up/down because that's the intended system behaviour by default

Comment: then you add tap gesture to search controller search and hide on tap of it